# Rails if statement for current user profile view and other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi I'm having some trouble getting different views to display based on whether or not the user being viewed is the logged in user.

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Devise

I've tried the code below but it always returns the template for the logged in user (where I have edit info links) rather than the one for the other users.

```
<% if user = current_user %>  
  <%= render 'users/myprofile' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'users/viewprofile' %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement should be..

```
<% if user == current_user %>
```

The reason being, = is for assignment, == is for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Check the sign of comparison. You have used equals to sign.

```
<% if user == current_user %>
```

`=` sign assigns the current user to `user` variable. Hence the condition will always be true unless there is no current user.